# In JavaScript, what is the main benefit of creating an object in one file, export and use it in other file

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I'm learning JavaScript and using [AWS SDK from JavaScript](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/).

Reading an IAM example from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/iam-examples-managing-users.html), i saw the following pattern:

- Create a file name `iamClient.js` where you instantiate an object and export it.
- Create another file where you import the client created above to use it.

What is the main benefit of doing this instead of just create and use the object in the same file ?

I know this is a small example and maybe there is no issue doing everything in the same file, but i'm more curious if this is just for organization/best practice if something bigger is created based on this sample or if there is some sort of technical reason. :)

Comment: Code re-use & keeping files smaller, it's way nicer editing files that are 100's of lines long, rather than 1000's of lines long.  In theory you could write all your Javascript in 1 file, in fact bundlers can be configured to do exactly that.  Put simply, while developing lots of files logically split is the norm, but when it comes to production less files are considered better.  Although even then with http2/spdy lots of files have the benefit of using cache more ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's how you'd create a configuration singleton for instance in another language.

- Creation of such object might be expensive in time sometimes so you create it once and then just reuse it :)
- During testing, if you provide a mock for your `iamClient` module you're set for all unit-tests (assuming you're using Jest or similar)
- It also helps you to *not repeat yourself* as it's a codesmell

Comment: Wow, this is the fastest answer i got here in StackOverflow. Thank you very much. It make sense now :D